# No key with alias 'foo' found in keystore keystore.jks

Tags: android, gradle, keystore, android-keystore

I have run`keytool -v -list -keystore keystore.jks` and made sure that the alias is key0, but even though I specify key0 as the alias in my gradle file, I still get the error "No key with alias 'foo' found in keystore keystore.jks". I don't know where it is getting this "foo" alias from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: here]
 bro first check your password first, if your password is correct then you can get the key Alias, Just put your password in the first field and then click on the tinny filder located on the field of Alias in Right side, new Dialog Box will be appear which shows your Key Alias, Happy coading.

Comment: Right, I did that,I have the right alias(key0) and passwords, but its not saying "No key with alias 'key0'", for some reason it is saying "No key with alias 'foo'". Nowhere (afaik) do I specify the alias as foo. I may have used foo on accident before somewhere.

Comment: ooh I get it, bro then surely check your path, it might be getting the the path of other JKS file

Comment: you were right, I had the full path to the store file, not the relative path in gradle. It was looking for my home folder in the project root folder.

Comment: thanks, then just mark the Ans right so that this question and answer will help other.

Comment: added key Alias but it shows no match found, but i didn't click on that file icon in alias, thanks your ans saved me @MR.Robot